# how to connect my pages with xmls in subfolders of views in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, namespaces

I have a problem with i am trying to use the xmls: views to connect my `collectionsViews` in `contentTemplate`
of my `AppShellPage`. but the problem is that I put them in sub folders of views. and it doesn't work he tells me that xmls: views is already

```
     xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Appli.views.cat"
               xmlns:views = "clr-namespace:Appli.views.dog"
                           BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                  <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
                <Tab Title="Home"
                     Icon="paw1Png.png">
                    <ShellContent Title="Cats"
                                  Icon="cat.png"
                                   Route="CatsRoute"
                                   ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
                    <ShellContent Title="Dogs"
                                  Icon="dog.png"
                                  Route="DogsRoute"
                                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}"
                                    />
```

[image: 1]

Comment: xmlns based on namespace not folder name whare you save the *.cs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the xaml namespace view 2 times while it must be unique,
the first definition is  `xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Appli.views.cat"` and the second definition is `xmlns:views = "clr-namespace:Appli.views.dog"`.

The sub folder where you are saving your class doesn't matter what matters is the namespace where the class is defined, What you can do is either to put `CatsPage` and `DogsPage` on the same namespace, let say `Appli.views.AnimalPages`:

**CatsPage.cs**

```
namespace Appli.views.AnimalPages {
     public Class CatsPage { }
}
```

**DogsPage.cs**

```
namespace Appli.views.AnimalPages {
     public Class DogsPage { }
}
```

Your xaml namespace becomes `xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Appli.views.AnimalPages"`